# How to share user permission across different servers and NFS folders?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, nfs, shared-folders

I have a 3 different servers running Ubuntu 20. One of them is configured as the NFS host, and the other two as clients. The clients can mount the NFS shared folders and can write content on it `sudo touch foo.txt`.

On the client servers, I have a wget process mirroring a website. I want my two clients servers to output the files from wget to `/nfs/shared` folder. On both servers, the process is executed like `www-data user wget (...) -o /nfs/shared`.

None of the servers can write into the folder due to `permission denied`. Reading other questions here it seems like my users must have the same `UUID` to make sure the permission mask works properly.

My question:

- How can I maintain a list of users common across my `n` servers to make sure all of them can write into `/nfs/shared`?

Comment: consider editting your second sentence to say *One of them is configured as the NFS server.*

Comment: the permissions are relevant on the nfs clients with regards to NFS shares, so make sure `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` is the same on all nfs clients.  And then as long as file/folder permissions then have correct `rwx` there will be no issues - it can be that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this, but by a very long way the most common ones are:

- manually by changing uids and/or replicating /etc/{passwd|shadow|group} - NOT recommended - even if you know what you are doing this will bite you in the bum
- Creating a group with a common GID on all hosts and basing permissions around that (still a workaround but a lot less hassle than trying to sync uids)
- NIS / NIS+ / yellow pages - an integrated/automated method of implementing the first approach. This is now fading into history - tooling still available but expect bit-rot on documentation
- LDAP - a PITA to setup but once configured correctly a no-brainer to keep running

Depending on the context and how the storage is being used for other things, you might be able to avoid the problem by using SMB.

Comment: Good pieces of info there... I am trying the SMB option with SAMBA implementation. Funny enough I can mount the shared resource on my local machine and see its content, but I cannot create any files on it... On the config I have set     `writeable = yes`, `guest ok = yes` just as PoC, but still getting permission denied...

At this point my main requirement is to allow the rest of the machines on my network to create/delete files from the shared location... Any guidance there?

Comment: From the info on this comment, I took the NFS approach. As my requirements only are to write/read files from a common location shared between "n" servers, I ended up setting nobody:nogroup ownership and exporting the directory with all_stash. It does not look particularly secure... but does the trick